# mysqli_stmt_num_rows, mysqli_stmt_execute and mysqli_store_result

Tags: php

I have the following function which is supposed to check if a new email address to be added into the database is already in there.

```
function duplicate_email($email_y){
    $dbCon = db_connect();
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbCon, $sql)) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email_y);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        //mysqli_store_result($dbCon);
        $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

        if($rows == 1){
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            mysqli_close($dbCon);
            return true;
            }
        else{
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            mysqli_close($dbCon);
            return false;
        }     
    }
}
```

This is where I use it:

```
if(duplicate_email($email) == true){
    echo 'Email [ '.$email.' ] seems to be already used';
}
```

The problem is that is does not detect, I've tested on an email address that is in the database and it fails, it passes over like its not there. 
Any thoughts where it fails?
thx

Comment: Just some questions back: Why do you use `mysqli_store_result`? Why do you use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows`?

Comment: mysqli_store_result was commented out, not using it :P sry, but with the second one is to get nr. rows selected?

Comment: Are there any hidden spaces stored in db with email?

Comment: Please follow the examples in the PHP manual: http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.num-rows - sorry if my questions back confused you. - Also in your case you can also select the `COUNT(*)` and `LIMIT 1` (both MySQL SQL).

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question, but defensive programming style would recommend that you change your statement to `if ($rows >= 1)` just in case your test email address is included in your database multiple times.

Also, you should handle the case of your `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare...)` not returning true. It'll just fall through to the rest of your code and return nothing, which I believe might be interpreted as false. At the very least, print out some debug code (or raise an exception) if that fails.